# RSpec testing a series of actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have a complex transaction process I want to test using RSpec. I would like to have some checking after each step. I only know how to test them in separate actions. So in each step, I have to add actions I already specified in previous steps as follow:

```
it "should add money to account A through deposit"
  a.deposit(10)
  a.balance.should == 10
end

it "should subtract money from A through transfer"
  a.deposit(10)
  a.transfer b, 5
  a.balance.should == 5
  b.balance.should == 5
end

it "should reverse transaction through reverse"
  a.deposit(10)
  a.transfer b, 5
  a.reserve b, 5
  a.balance.should == 10
  b. balance.should == 10
end
```

What I want to do is:

```
it "should perform a series of actions successfully"
  a.deposit(10)
   # checking here
  a.transfer b, 5
    # checking here
  a.reserve b, 5
    # checking here  
end
```

Is it possible to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original tests are actually better, because if one fails you'll have a better understanding of where the problem was. If you want to reduce the duplication between each test, use before(:each)

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I think before(:all), which creates dependency for examples would be useful for me because I may have a dozen of steps to walk through.